# Ajax issues on WordPress

Tags: ajax

I think the issue is that Civi is (1) not enquing the versions of jQuery that come with WordPress and (2) the code is not written for noconflict mode.

```
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=NJqDM:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_defaults' of undefined
at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=NJqDM:8
at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=NJqDM:103
```

?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:32 Uncaught ReferenceError: cj is not defined
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:32
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:192 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:192
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:208 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:208
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:259 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:259
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:400 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:400
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:403 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:403
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:563 Uncaught ReferenceError: cj is not defined
    at skipPaymentMethod (?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:563)
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:577
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:618 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
    at ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:618
?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2:621 Uncaught ReferenceError: cj is not defined

Comment: Make sure you have resource URL and directories path configured correctly in `Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs`

Comment: Every time I login, Civi tells me that there's an error in the resource URL, yet as far as I can see it's set according to the documentation to "https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm"  (see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-cms/#update-the-resource-urls_1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross check each and every path configured in `Administer -> System Settings -> Resource URLs`. Set them as per your site configurations.

- CiviCRM Resource URL : is the URL path to your civicrm directory - Eg `http://example.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm`
- Image Upload URL: is the URL path where your image will be stored. Eg `http://example.org/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute`
- Extension Resource URL: is the URL path of the extensions used in your site.

Navigate to `Administer -> System Settings -> Directories` and set the path as per your needs.

- Image Directory: should be the same path as above(Image Upload URL) without the URL part. Eg `/var/www/site-name/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute`
- Extensions Directory: same path as set for extensions in the resource URL(without the URL part). Eg `/var/www/site-name/path/to/extensions/`

Similarly, set all the paths and check if it fixes your site display.

Comment: Paths and URLs are correct:

https://i.imgur.com/bQq6CF4.png

https://i.imgur.com/w0vqN4V.png

But the JS errors persist on the contribute page 

https://i.imgur.com/1DfK7Vi.png

Comment: pretty late but have you tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the menu with `http://example.org.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1 `?

Comment: Yes, more than once